# What are the purposes for the Location Select and Person Select cursors?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, themes, mouse-cursor

I have been making custom cursors for Windows for a living. My whole time of doing so, I memorized all 15 roles. However, when I used Windows 10 in 2019 due to an update, I noticed two extra roles named Location Select ([image: default Windows 10 location select cursor]) and Person Select ([image: default Windows 10 person select cursor]). I barely see these get used anytime I use Windows 10 or 11, but I have to make them anyways, since publishing these cursor sets without those two roles gets other users to tell me to add them. What are their purposes and use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much information available about these cursors.
Here is what I have managed to gather (and it's not much).
These cursors are currently rarely used, and some cursors packs
don't bother with implementing them.

The "Location Select" cursor, typically a small hand icon with a pointing
finger. It may mean that clicking will lead to a new location or
precipitate an action.

The "Person Select" cursor, typically a small person icon,
is often used to select user profiles, avatars, or other elements
of users.

Comment: I see. I was wondering why there were barely utilized. I believe that Person Select would've been utilized more than Location Select, since there are more people to click on in apps than locations as far as I know. Thanks!